# Display my raw data source as a table in Data Studio

Tags: google-bigquery, looker-studio

I have a BigQuery data source linked with my Data Studio report. I want to be able to display the raw data source (without any aggregations) as a table on my report, without navigating to BigQuery.
Is there any proper way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way I can think about is Inserting a [Table](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7189044?hl=en), add all the columns as dimensions and remove all metrics.

Rows would still be aggregated by all dimensions, so you won't see duplicates, also, it seems that sorting cannot be avoided, so rows would be sorted by a column of your choosing.